# How can i find out if a certain number is in my array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to figure out if a number is in my array:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "3,4,5" } 

 if (in_array('3', $array)) {
      echo 'in array';
 } else {
     echo 'not in array';
 }
```

The result is `not in array` but I expect `in array`

Comment: `3` isn't in the array, but `3,4,5` is. That's why it's saying "not in array". You need to either split the array into separate numbers or split the string into an array and then search that new array.

Comment: is it possible to know if `3` is inside the array?

Comment: Yes. Look at `explode`.

Comment: It looks like you have a string instead of array. Go ahead with array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) [***in case of current scenario only***]

```
if (strpos($array[0],'3') !==false) {
      echo 'in array';
 } else {
     echo 'not in array';
 }
```

Output:- https://eval.in/932541

Or you can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
 [***for multiple scenario***]

```
$array = [0=>"3,4,5"];

$array = explode(',',$array[0]);

if (in_array(3, $array)) {
      echo 'in array';
 } else {
     echo 'not in array';
 }
```

Output:- https://eval.in/932542  Or https://eval.in/932545

Comment: This is working!

Comment: @Jarla  glad to help you :):)

Comment: @mickmackusa  when i checked the question one answer is already given which actually not addressing the problem correctly. As well as i have similar other approaches to do the same. That's why i posted the answer.

Comment: the `strpos()` method is a bad one because it will give false positive matching.  consider `33,44,55`  Everytime such a simple question is asked, you know it is a duplicate somewhere on this site.

Answer (score 5):

You should try like this, with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

```
<?php
$array = explode(",","3,4,5");

 if (in_array(3, $array)) {
      echo 'in array';
 } else {
     echo 'not in array';
 }
?>
```

Demo : https://eval.in/932540

Comment: But this is an answer for a string `"3,4,5"` and not for my array `array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "3,4,5" }`

Comment: @Jarla : this is idea for string , its' not matter that where from you get this string, in your case it is from array.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to move over all items in an array and check its content with the needle you want to find.

```
 function isInArray($array,$needle){
       foreach($array as $arrayItem){
          if(strpos($arrayItem,$needle)!==false)
             return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow.  Keep editing.  `foreach` and `in`?  Show me a demo link please.

Comment: This answer will incorrectly match when the string is `33,44,55`

Comment: if we are assuming that explode is already called before it hits `isInArray()` then: 1. you are missing a vital ingredient in the answer and 2. `strpos()` is overkill and potentially incorrect as it will match any value that contains the `$needle` substring.

Comment: @Jarla If you have upvoted this answer please reconsider because it is not good and potentially wrong.  Not every posted answer is an upvote-worthy one on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

=> Use `explode()` Function .

```
$array = explode(",","3,4,5");

 if (in_array(3, $array)) {
      echo 'in array';
 } else {
     echo 'not in array';
```